# D3js- crossfiltering in csv data

Tags: csv, d3.js

I want to read a csv file which contains about 5 lakh (5*10^5) records. After reading the csv file, I want to filter this data using crossfiltering in d3.js.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693403/d3-crossfilter-basic-example

Comment: [crossfilter](http://square.github.com/crossfilter/) is your friend.