# D3 Crossfilter simple example (without using dc.js)

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

Is there are simple way to implement crossfilter with d3.js charts? What would be the basic example? Let's say, for a similar graphs like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 .

A similar question has been asked before ([D3 Crossfilter basic example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693403/d3-crossfilter-basic-example)), but I did not find answers for it very supportive, since I am interested in cases in which I could do it without using dc.js (in case of building more customized charts).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 Crossfilter basic example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693403/d3-crossfilter-basic-example)

Comment: The 2nd answer to the question you linked contains links to examples. (In fact, the same ones I was about to answer this question with.) Because of this, I'm going to flag this as a duplicate.